# Support Vector Machines

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, classification, svm

I had these questions in an exam today. State True or False and explain.

1. If k<sub>1</sub>(.,.) and k<sub>2</sub>(.,.) are two valid kernel functions, then if h = k<sub>1</sub> - k<sub>2</sub>, is h(.,.) a valid kernel function?
2. A standard soft margin SVM is used to classify data set. We have a fixed C parameter. Two different algorithms A<sub>1</sub> and A<sub>2</sub> are used to obtain the support vector set {S: 
   α
   <sub>i</sub> > 0}. Call them S1 and S2. Is S1 = S2 in all cases? Assume both algorithm use the same kernel function.

EDITED:

I guessed as:

1. As kernel function need to be positive semi definite (PSD), the difference between two kernel functions need not be PSD. Hence FALSE.
2. α<sub>i</sub> can be different among the two algorithms, the number of support vectors can differ as well. Hence FALSE again.

Comment: try http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I had clearly mentioned this is an exam question. I had no clue about these questions. I only know about kernel functions, but not about operations between kernel functions. I only guessed: as kernel function need to be positive semi definite (PSD), the difference between two kernel functions need not be PSD. Hence FALSE.
For the second one, I guessed as αi can be different among the two algorithms, the number of support vectors can differ as well. Hence FALSE again. 
Anyways, I was merely guessing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving a homework.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse If you mean that you need to know about the two algorithms A1 and A2, NO, our Professor didn't specify what the algorithms were.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse He only mentioned in class that in order to determine C and alpha, we have to use the Grid approach along with the cross validation method. I am not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: I received my answer sheet today and both are FALSE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) constant 0 is a kernel, constant 1 is a kernel, too. But 0-1=-1 is not PSD.

Thus false IMHO.

B) Assuming 2D data, where x=0 for Class 1, x=1 for Class 2, and y is uniformly random. Any vector from each class is as good a support vector as the others, yielding the same hyperplane. Visually:

```
x1 | y1
   |
x2 | y2
```

Which SVM is better, the one using x1 and y1 as support vectors, or the one using x2 and y2?